# bash xterm : how to get command line before typing enter

Tags: bash, xterm, buffer

I try to define a custom behaviour of the backward-kill-word function in bash xterm.
For that, I need to catch the command line before validate it.
For instances, if I type `sdcds/edfdD sdf/sdf` without typing enter, I want by using a shortcut like `esc + backspace` to catch the line `sdcds/edfdD sdf/sdf` in a temporary variable to apply a sed after.
I have already written the sed and the bind command but I cannot find anywhere how to catch the `buffer` command line.

**Update from Answer**

Ok thanks a lot, I think I'm not clear enough in my explanation.
What I want to do is to create a function and the related bind key in the bash.rc to modify the text in the command line.
Imagine, I want to define a function which removes the command line (before typing enter) till "/" for example and only till /, I could write in my .bash.rc :

```
function backward-delete-to-slash () { echo $BUFFER_COMMAND_LINE | sed  's:\(.*[/][/]*).*:\1:';}

bind -x '"\e\d": backward-delete-to-slash'
```

My problem is to catch the command line into a `$BUFFER_COMMAND_LINE` variable.
If I had this variable, I could do for instance :

```
$: sdffs/dsfd dsfsdf/dfdsf (without typing enter)
```

<kbd>esc</kbd> + <kbd>backspace</kbd>

```
$: sdffs/dsfd dsfsdf/
```

So I hope to be more exhaustive.

Comment: Please do not post answer to your question, use the edit button to add additional information to a question. Please review the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq) since this is not a traditional forum

Answer (score 0):

If you know vi a bit, try this:

```
$ set -o vi
$ bind vi-yank-to '\ey'
$ type-your-text-here - then press Home to go to begin-of-line, esc-y
```

The line is in a buffer now. Press Ctrl-c to get a new line, then

```
$ sed something-and-then esc-p
```

The text from the buffer should appear.